# SED match pattern in two lines

Tags: regex, sed

For the replacement of string between two patterns i use:

String i want to change: `<name>FOO</name>`

I use for this:

```
s#(<name>).*?(</name)#\1xxxxxxxxxxx\2#g;
```

I'm looking for solution, when 1st patters exist in two lines:

```
<attributes>
      <name>AUTOR</name>
      <value>FOO</value>
      <type>1</type>
 </attributes>
```

I want to replace `BAR`
I've tried something like this, but with no results:

```
s#(AUTOR</name>\n\r<value>).*?(</value)#\1xxxxxxxxxxx\2#g;
```

EDIT:
I was convinced to use `XMLStarlet` instead of `SED`.

Comment: If you give us a valid XML file, we can give you a solution that uses an XML parser to do this.  The `sed` utility is inappropriate for parsing and modifying XML data.

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) to the famous StackOverflow post about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line-oriented tools are generally inappropriate for parsing and modifying XML data. Instead of `sed`, consider using something like [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

Using XMLStarlet:

```
$ cat data.xml
<attributes>
      <name>AUTOR</name>
      <value>FOO</value>
      <type>1</type>
 </attributes>

$ xml ed -u '/attributes/value' -v NEWFOO data.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<attributes>
  <name>AUTOR</name>
  <value>NEWFOO</value>
  <type>1</type>
</attributes>
```

If you have a more interesting XML:

```
<books>
  <book>
    <attributes>
      <name>Author 1</name>
      <value>FOO</value>
      <type>1</type>
    </attributes>
  </book>
  <book>
    <attributes>
      <name>Author 2</name>
      <value>FOO</value>
      <type>1</type>
    </attributes>
  </book>
</books>
```

.. and you would like to change `FOO` for only "Author 2", then

```
$ xml ed -u '//attributes[name="Author 2"]/value' -v NEWFOO data.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
  <book>
    <attributes>
      <name>Author 1</name>
      <value>FOO</value>
      <type>1</type>
    </attributes>
  </book>
  <book>
    <attributes>
      <name>Author 2</name>
      <value>NEWFOO</value>
      <type>1</type>
    </attributes>
  </book>
</books>
```

Comment: Ok, this is very interesting solution, since cygwin has this feature. Thanks a lot :)