# SED command to replace test with newline break

Tags: sed

I'm in need of some help, I need to replace text on a page using SED command with other text but it just will not work for me.

Need to replace this one:

```
            <key>disableMailRecentsSyncing</key>
            <true />
            <key>allowMailDrop</key>
            <false />
            <key>PreventMove</key>
            <true />
```

With this one:

```
            <key>disableMailRecentsSyncing</key>
            <false />
            <key>allowMailDrop</key>
            <true />
            <key>PreventMove</key>
            <false />
```

I've tried the following but it will not work:

```
sed -i 's/<key>disableMailRecentsSyncing</key>                 <true />                 <key>allowMailDrop</key>                 <false />                 <key>PreventMove</key>                 <true />/<key>disableMailRecentsSyncing</key>                 <false />                 <key>allowMailDrop</key>                 <true />                 <key>PreventMove</key>                 <false />/g' input.txt
```

Comment: `sed` processes the input line by line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SED match pattern in two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367648/sed-match-pattern-in-two-lines)

Answer (score 3):

For editing XML, use an XML-aware tool. For example, negating all the listed keys can be done in [XSH](http://p3rl.org/XSH) (a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML)) using the following command:

```
rename xsh:if(self::true, "false", "true")
       (//false[preceding-sibling::key[1]="allowMailDrop"]
       | //true[preceding-sibling::key[1]="PreventMove"
                or preceding-sibling::key[1]="disableMailRecentsSyncing"]) ;
```

Note that I'm the current maintainer of the tool.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- data is nicely formatted as in the question (otherwise a proper XML/HTML-aware tool may be easier to use than re-inventing a parser)
- objective is to toggle the current value (ie, `true` becomes `false` and `false` becomes `true`)
- `true/false` values are all lowercase
- `true/false` are always preceded by a `<`

With a view towards an `awk` solution I'd want the patterns (to search for) placed into a file as this allows for flexibility without having to hardcode the solution, eg:

```
$ cat key.list
disableMailRecentsSyncing
allowMailDrop
PreventMove
```

My input file with some additional data:

```
$ cat input.data
<key>disableMailRecentsSyncing</key>       # match but ...
<sometimes true />                         #    leave "true" alone

<key>disableMailRecentsSyncing</key>       # match so ...
<true />                                   #   switch to "false"
<key>allowMailDrop</key>                   # match so ...
<false />                                  #   switch to "true"
<key>PreventMove</key>                     # match so ...
<true />                                   #   switch to "false"

<key>allowMailDrop</key>                   # match but ...
<Tuesday />                                #   ignore
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==NR    { keys[$1]; next }
           { split($0,arr,"[<>]") }
toggle     { if ( arr[2] ~ /^true/  ) gsub(/<true/, "<false")
             if ( arr[2] ~ /^false/ ) gsub(/<false/,"<true" )
             toggle=0
           }
           { if ( arr[3] in keys) toggle=1 }
1
' key.list input.data
```

This generates:

```
<key>disableMailRecentsSyncing</key>
<sometimes true />

<key>disableMailRecentsSyncing</key>
<false />
<key>allowMailDrop</key>
<true />
<key>PreventMove</key>
<false />

<key>allowMailDrop</key>
<Tuesday />
```

Due to the use of 2 input files OP will not be able to use (`GNU`) `awk -i inplace` so the output will need to be saved to a temp file and then copying/moving the temp file to replace the current file.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat <<\! >matchFile
        <key>disableMailRecentsSyncing</key>
        <true />
        <key>allowMailDrop</key>
        <false />
        <key>PreventMove</key>
        <true />
!
cat <<\! >replaceFile
        <key>disableMailRecentsSyncing</key>
        <false />
        <key>allowMailDrop</key>
        <true />
        <key>PreventMove</key>
        <false />
!
cat file <(echo MATCH) matchFile <(echo REPLACE) replaceFile |
sed -Ez ':a;s/(.*)(.*MATCH\1REPLACE(.*))/\3\2/;ta;s/(.*)MATCH.*//'
```

To replace the original file, use:

```
sed -E -i 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/$/\n$(echo MATCH;cat matchFile;echo REPLACE;cat replaceFile)/
           s/.*/echo "&"/e;:a;s/(.*)(.*MATCH\1REPLACE(.*))/\3\2/;ta;s/(.*)MATCH.*/\1/' file
```

The solution appends a delimiter `MATCH` followed by the `matchFile`, followed by a second delimiter `REPLACE` followed by the `replaceFile`.

Then using a loop and pattern matching (involving back references) the `matchFile` is matched against places in the original file and replaced by the text in the `replaceFile`.